# Two materials in one model # A-Frame

Tags: aframe

Engine A-Frame.

I had a 3d-model with two surfaces: metal and glass.

How can I assign two materials with different options in one model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** October 2017 - A-Frame 0.7.x:

A-Frame 0.7.x has made the glTF2 standard over glTF1. All you have to do is to use the [`gltf-model`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/gltf-model.html#sidebar) component directly.

**Old answer** - A-Frame 0.6.x:

You can do this in your modelling software and export your asset in [glTF2](https://www.khronos.org/gltf) format. In order to load it into A-Frame use [A-Frame extras package](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders).